# No customer header sent when using UbikLoadPack Monitoring plugin for JMeter with Dynatrace

Tags: performance, jmeter, apm, dynatrace, ubikloadpack

I just started to test the [UbikLoadPack](https://ubikloadpack.com) Monitoring plugin for JMeter with Dynatrace (OneAgent).

While the metrics creation seems to be working just fine, I can’t get the plugin to add any header.

My understanding is that [UbikLoadPack APM Monitoring](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=26-lFhJB-IE) is supposed to add specific headers. I don’t see them in the sent requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a [Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) as a child of Test plan:

[image: Add Header Manager]

You'll end up with something like this:

[image: Test plan with UbikLoadPack Monitoring plugin]